# sidebar height doesn't 100% in css

Tags: css, height, sidebar

I have problem in layout of page in css. I have sidebar that height doesn't 100%. I want to show sidebar in 100%, but I can't. how to increase height of sidebar to 100%.

thanks a lot for helping
my css:

```css
body {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
#sidebar {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background-color: #222A2D;
}
.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.main {
    margin-left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 15px;
    color:red;
    padding-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<body id="mainbody">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header>Header</header>
        
        <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>menu1</li>
                <li>menu2</li>
                <li>menu3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="main" id="main">
            Main content
            <br>
            Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vs5sgand/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.sidebar` has a float and is absolute positioned. Those two don't work together. Remove the float from `.sidebar`. Also add `position: relative;` to `.container-fluid`, or else `.sidebar` doesn't now which height it should take.

```
.sidebar {
    width: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background-color: #222A2D;
}

.container-fluid {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/vs5sgand/3/

Comment: Thanks for helping but remain other problem. when content was blank, sidebar height not 100%. please see http://jsfiddle.net/vs5sgand/4/

Answer (score -2):

Make the layout with table. Many thinks useing table as a layout is a bad idea but you can get full control on your layout with table.